# Trouble loading R package data

Tags: r, namespaces, package

I've developed a R package but for some reason the dataset that goes with the package is not being loaded properly when the package is Roxygenised and installed. I have a .R script in the R folder of the package that looks like this

```
#' Score Card
#' @docType data
#' @name scoreCard
#' @aliases scoreCard
#' @format An object of class \code{data.frame} with 119 rows and 3 columns.
#' \describe{
#'   \item{Category}{The Category for which an observation is made}
#'   \item{Observation}{The possible responses given for each category}
#'   \item{Score}{The score allocated against a response for each category}
#' }
#' @source Internal
#' @usage scoreCard
#' @keywords datasets
NULL
```

This creates an .Rmd file for the dataset when `Roxygenise` is called but when I try to call the data set using `packageName::scoreCard` it states `'scoreCard' is not an exported object from 'namespace:packageName'`. Can anyone spot what I might have done wrong in the above script or any other ideas of what might be going wrong, I'm at a bit of a loss? (The data set is stored in the data folder of the package as per normal.) Afraid I can't share the data or package sorry.

Comment: How is the dataset stored? As a `.RData` file? Does `data("scoreCard", package = "packageName")` followed by `scoreCard` work? I don't think it's a documentation related issue

Comment: Hi it's stored as `.rda`. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: This does work but you shouldn't need to use data, as I understand it a dataset stored in the data file of the package should install when documented in an R script as the above so you can call it simply by stating its name, such as mtcars dataset

Comment: I agree. BTW why do you think it's related to documentation? Documentation is a must, of course, but things should work with or without it.

Comment: It may not be related to documentation but I can't think why else I'm getting the aforementioned error.`scoreCard' is not an exported object from 'namespace:packagename`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right I didn't realise I needed LazyData: true in my description file. Should have read this more carefully: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html